# How to change "report is being generated" in report viewer

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, report

I'm working with SQL Server reporting service to create my reports. When I show the report in "Report viewer" on my Asp.net page, how can I change "report is being generated"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the IReportViewerMessages Interface... see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportviewermessages.aspx

It allows applications to provide customized user interface messages.